Prove a special determinant formula
Let $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$ be column vectors of $K$ and $M$ components respectively, and $q$, $r$  be two scalars. Also, $I_k$ and $I_m$ are identity matrices of size $K$ by $K$ and $M$ by $M$. Let $\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{a}^T$ be a $K$ by $K$ matrix one gets by multiplying a column vector by a row vector (similarly for $\textbf{b}$).
How does one prove that the determinant of:
$$
q*(I_k \otimes I_m) + r*(I_k  \otimes[\textbf{b}\cdot\textbf{b}^T]) + r*([\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{a}^T] \otimes I_m)
$$
is equal to
$$
q^{(K-1)(M-1)}*(q+r*\textbf{b}^T.\textbf{b})^{K-1}*(q+r*\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a})^{M-1}*(q+r*(\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}^T.\textbf{b}))
$$
Note that $\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a}$ is the sum of squares of all components of $\textbf{a}$ (same for $\textbf{b}$).
This formula is important when proving that a certain test statistic has a chi-squared distribution (something I could not find in literature).
After getting the crucial hint below, my question boils down to: How does one prove that the determinant of $$q*I_{k+m} + r*M$$where $M$ is an $k+m$ by $k+m$ matrix with the following block structure: its main-diagonal blocks are $\textbf{b}^T.\textbf{b}*I_k$ and $\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a}*I_m$ while the off-diagonals are $\textbf{a}\otimes\textbf{b}$ and
$\textbf{b}\otimes\textbf{a}$, equal to
$$
q*(q+r*\textbf{b}^T.\textbf{b})^{k-1}*(q+r*\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a})^{m-1}*(q+r*(\textbf{a}^T.\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}^T.\textbf{b}))
$$
This is easy to prove using a formula for the determinant of a 2 by 2 block matrix.

Should not you give a reason for -1 score?

By A x B, do you mean the Kronecker product $A \otimes B$? That seems to match your verbal description, but it's not clear what "expanding" should mean here and it can't hurt to check

Yes, that's what it is,, made into a single KM by KM matrix - I was trying to be explicit about it as the Kronecker product is effectively  K by M by K by M dimensional,

Hint: Note that your matrix can be written in the form $qI_{mn} + rAA^T$, where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
I_k \otimes \mathbf b & \mathbf a \otimes I_m
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
From there, you can use Sylvester's determinant theorem.

Is you brackets  [ A  B ] an alternate notation for Kronecker product of A and B?

@Honza No, $\otimes$ is my notation for the Kronecker product, why would I indicate the same operation in two different ways? $[A\ B]$ is a block matrix

@Honza For example, with $\mathbf a = (1,2)$ and $\mathbf b = (3,4)$, we get
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \
4 & 0 & 0 & 1 \
0 & 3 & 2 & 0 \
0 & 4 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
